# cheerio missing div elements, why?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

Here's a very simple example so that you can reproduce the bug quickly. Thanks.

```js
// main.js

const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let data = fs.readFileSync("tmp.html", 'utf8');
let data2 = fs.readFileSync("tmp2.html", 'utf8');

const $ = cheerio.load(data);
const $2 = cheerio.load(data2);

$('body idx\\:entry').eq(0).text()
// '
//         
//           abaniquear
//         
//         '

// -> Umm, what's happening? 
// -> Under the `idx:entry` element, there are three children, `idx:orth`, `div`, `div`. 
// -> But in the above only the first two `idx:orth`, `div` has been detected thus `text()` returns only this 
// -> while it should return `abanicar .. vt .. (Andes) .. see also: abanicar`. 
// -> weird, right??

$2('body idx\\:entry').eq(0).text()
// ' 
//         
//           abaniqueo
//         
//         
//           
//             
//               m
//             
//             
//                fanning
//             
//           
//         
//       '

// -> Yes, this is a normal output. 
// -> It `text()`-ed the three `idx:orth`, `div`, `div` children elements.
```

```html
<!-- tmp.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <mbp:pagebreak /><a id="filepos22099" /><mbp:frameset>
      <idx:entry scriptable="yes"
        ><idx:orth value="abaniquear"></idx:orth>
        <div>
          <div><b>abaniquear</b></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <span><i>vt</i></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>
                <span><i>(Andes)</i></span></span
              >
              <div>see also: <a href="#filepos65523">abanicar</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </idx:entry>
      <hr />
    </mbp:frameset>
    <mbp:pagebreak />
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- tmp2.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <mbp:pagebreak /><a id="filepos22099" /><mbp:frameset>
      <idx:entry scriptable="yes"
        ><idx:orth value="abaniqueo"
          ><idx:infl> <idx:iform name="" value="abaniqueos" /></idx:infl
        ></idx:orth>
        <div>
          <div><b>abaniqueo</b></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <span><i>m</i></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span> <span>fanning</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </idx:entry>
      <hr />
    </mbp:frameset>
    <mbp:pagebreak />
  </body>
</html>
```

SO told me `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.` so I'll say again here,

Umm, what's happening?

In the `$('body idx\\:entry').eq(0).text()` where `tmp.html` is loaded,
under the `idx:entry` element, there are three children, `idx:orth`, `div`, `div`.

But in the above only the first two `idx:orth`, `div` has been detected thus `text()` returns only this while it should return `abanicar .. vt .. (Andes) .. see also: abanicar`.
weird, right??

In the `$2('body idx\\:entry').eq(0).text()` where `tmp2.html` is loaded,
Yes, this is a normal output.
It `text()`-ed the three `idx:orth`, `div`, `div` children elements.

So, how can I fix this bug? Thanks, again.

Comment: This isn't valid HTML, but if you print Cheerio's parsed HTML, you can see the tag was moved in the top example but not the bottom. Where is this content coming from?

Comment: Thanks, the html is from a mobi ebook file generated from the mobi python library.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by specifying `xml: true`.

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(data, {
  xml: true,
});
```